# ftp sending from windows to linux shows java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, windows, ftp, connection-timeout, apache-commons-net

I am sending a file via ftp from Windows 2008 r2 server(64) to CentOS 64.

I can send a file via ftp with dos command line. It has no warnings and errors. The problem is when I try to do same thing via java code. It shows error like Below.

(sorry. I can not post full messages. Somehow I can not drag and copy in windows console)

```
java.net.ConnectionEception: Connection time out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnecet(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:894)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:633)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:624)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:1976)
...
```

telnet ip port connects fine. login also succeed. But when I call FTPClient.storeFile() method it shows errors or delaying endless.

What else should I check more?

Comment: probably a firewall issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- check firewall ( @see: ftp PORT command description)
- try passive mode
- webdav or anything but ftp (which doesn't have PORT command alike abilities)

Comment: Thanks. I solved this. In fact, I was called enterPassiveMode() method. And errors disappear as I erase that code. I think sometimes ActiveMode is right. I should study more. Thanks a lot :D